# Hiding table column on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day, Im trying to hide a table column. I tried setting it up using .hide() but it doesnt work. It works on check box checked and unchecked but I want to hide it on page load. I tried display:none but it messes up my canvas. Here it the code. Thank you so much.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('.containerblock').hide();
        $('.containercheckbox').hide();
        $(".headertrading").hide();
        $(".tradingtabtd").hide();

$(".tradingcheckbox").click(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('.headertrading').show(200);
            $(".tradingtabtd").show(200);

            $(".tradingcheckbox").prop("checked", this.checked);
        } else {
            $(".headertrading").hide(300);
            $(".tradingtabtd").hide(300);
            $(".tradingcheckbox").prop("checked", false);
        }
        });
});
```

Comment: Pls give us your HTML as well :)

Comment: Will do. Thank youuu

Comment: @Phong here it is https://codepen.io/JLMG/pen/BaQqaxo I added it on the pen cause its to long here